# Can we use "RSVP" interchangeably with "RRSP"?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

I received an email with the "RRSP" abbreviation.

> "RRSP by 1 Nov 2011 to Willy Milly."

Upon checking with [Thesaurus.com](http://thesaurus.com/browse/RRSP), it is a synonym of "RSVP".

Can one use "RRSP" and "RSVP" interchangeably?

Comment: I've never seen RRSP before. Do you know what it stands for? By the way it's 'RSVP' not 'RVSP'.

Comment: @snubian I've fixed the 'RVSP' typos.

Comment: @Snubian me neither. I really want to know now.

Comment: Hi Snubian, I am also quite surprise to see the RRSP too. You can refer to Gnawme answer - some more the link in the answer have a funny quote - "RRSP vs RSVP, putting money away for the future vs spending it on a party …"

Comment: Reply Real Soon Please?

Comment: @BrianNixon. Wow! That phrase `Reply Real Soon Please` is excellent. +1 for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RSVP means *répondez, s’il vous plaît* – “please reply.”

While Thesaurus.com lists RRSP as a synonym of RSVP, the link for [RRSP](http://thesaurus.com/browse/RRSP) takes you right back to RSVP.

[This person](https://pinklea.wordpress.com/2009/12/19/repondez-sil-vous-plait/) faced the same dilemma of seeing RRSP on an invitation:

> At the bottom of the invitation, it says “RRSP” – which is, obviously,
>   the acronym for “Registered Retirement Savings Plan”.
>
> So now I simply don’t know what to do. Should I reply to these people
>   to tell them that we would love to come to their party, or should I
>   simply donate some money to their RRSP?

The bottom line: RRSP is *not* a synonym of RSVP. Use RSVP when you mean RSVP.

Comment: The link your provided is very funny. Someone even say - "RRSP vs RSVP, putting money away for the future vs spending it on a party …". Ok, so, both RRSP and RSVP can be use interchangeable. Thanks.

Comment: @LarryMorries: No! RRSP means "Registered Retirement Savings Plan". Just use RSVP, it means what you want it to mean.

Comment: I'm not sure how `RRSP` could possibly be a synonym for `RSVP`, since *respondez s'il vous plait* only has one "R" in it. `RSP` or `RVP` would be somewhat believable. If I saw `RRSP` on an invitation, I'd be very confused as well, and assume that the host had made a very strange typo.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: I think it's a typo, myself. The only phrase I could find for RRSP that didn't have anything to do with retirement was "Resource Reservation Setup Protocol." I have no idea why Thesaurus.com lists RRSP as a synonym for RSVP.

Comment: There are few other here [RRSP](http://www.abbreviations.com/RRSP), none mention it. Interesting, there seems to be no evidence that RRSP means RSVP, but Roget's 21st Century Thesaurus, Third Edition is what the thesaurus.com is based on.